# xcode how to remove signature from email when calling MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have app that generates an email (recipient, subject, body) so when the user presses done it fills all those things out and then they can just send it.  Is there a way to remove their signature (if its present) from the body?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the only way to change that is going to Settings->Mail and changing it.